# PDE with Lagrange's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following equation:

\begin{align} xu_x + u_y &= 3u \\ u(x, 0) &= x\end{align}

I wanted to solve it with Lagrange's method:

$$ \text{d}t = \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \text{d}y = \frac{\text{d}u}{3u}$$

Eq.1:
$$ \frac{\text{d}x}{x} = \text{d}y \quad \implies \quad \text{ln}(x) = y + C$$
which gives the first surface
$$ \phi_1 = xe^{-y} $$

and Eq.2:
$$ \text{d}y = \frac{\text{d}u}{3u}$$
which gives the second surface:

$$\phi_2 = ue^{-3y}$$

so $$u(x, y) = F(ue^{-3y}, xe^{-y}) \implies u(x, y) = ue^{-3y} + f(xe^{-y}) $$
which gives:
$$ u(x, y) = \frac{1}{1-e^{-3y}}\cdot f(xe^{-y}) $$

but I can't plug in the initial condition $ u(x, 0) = x $ due to division by zero...
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you're using the method of characteristic, but I'm not familiar with the conventions (notation, terminology) you're using, so I cannot follow the reasoning. There must a mistake somewhere, as I got a different result: $u(x,y) = e^{3y} \cdot u(x e^{-y}, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculus is correct up to :
$$u(x, y) = F(ue^{-3y}, xe^{-y}) \implies u(x, y) = ue^{-3y} + f(xe^{-y}) \quad\text{is not correct.}$$
The correct relationship is :
$$F(ue^{-3y}, xe^{-y})=0 \implies
ue^{-3y}=f\left( xe^{-y}\right)$$
$$u(x,y)=e^{3y}f\left( xe^{-y}\right)$$
Then is easy to find the particular solution which satisfies  $u(x,0)=x$ :
$$u(x,y)=x\,e^{2y}$$
Note : $F(ue^{-3y}, xe^{-y})=0$ is equivalent to $G(ue^{-3y}, xe^{-y})=$constant , with arbitrary related functions $F$ and $G$.